# Can You Hold the Stone that Wall of Stone Springs From?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting

Relevant Quotes:

> A nonmagical wall of solid stone springs into existence at a point you choose within range. The wall is 6 inches thick and is composed of ten 10-foot-by-10-foot panels. Each panel must be contiguous with at least on other panel. Alternatively, you can create 10-foot-by-20-foot panels that are only 3 inches thick....

> ...The wall can have any shape you desire, though it can’t occupy the same space as a creature or object. the wall doesn’t need to be vertical or resting on any firm foundation. It must, however, merge with and be solidly supported by existing stone.

If you start with a 10 foot long, 3 inch wide, 3 inch thick stone rod, for example, and you had enough strength to support it, **would you be able to hold the point at which wall of stone comes into existence?**

Comment: A single 10'x10'x6" panel weighs  7-8 thousand lbs, depending on the type of stone. How do you attain the strength required to support that?

Comment: @MannerPots Very valid point, but I'll leave the question up for theory's sake. About 9 large creatures each outfitted with a Belt of Storm Giant Strength would be enough, so there would likely be changes to the specifications of the stone being held to allow for that, but the point is still valid, if highly unlikely.

Comment: What would be the purpose?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Kirt No current purpose, but there was potential if the wall could be used as a portable shield/obstacle. However, as in my previous comment, and as pointed out by MannerPots, the strength required was a huge limiting factor, and as pointed out by NotArch's answer, is impossible. Plus, I'm probably better off using Stone Shape first before trying to use Wall of Stone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No

As you quoted in the text for *Wall of Stone*:

> It must, however, merge with and be solidly supported by existing stone.

If it is solidly supported by existing stone, then you simply aren't holding it up.

If you are holding it up, it's not solidly supported and doesn't meet the requirements of the spell.

You can put your hand under it and attempt to *pretend* to hold it, but that's up to the bystanders and how gullible they are.

Comment: Thank you; I realize now that the answer was in a couple words of the description that I missed.